# XHTML W3C Compliance, multiple information in src attribute

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c-validation

We are building an image carousel, it displays clickable thumbnails that when clicked, displays the actual image.  We therefore need both url to appears in the Html.  Since there is no "actualImageUrl" attribute defined in the img tag, we figured out that we could build the thumbnail url like this : `/thumb.png?altUrl=actualImageUrl.png`.  The server does not care of the actualImageUrl querystring param and we can use javascript to parse the scr attribute and figure out the actualImage Url.

How W3C valid is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is valid as a `src` attribute value, in the XHTML meaning for “valid” (a formal thing). It is also otherwise correct to have a query part in such a value and use it in client-side scripting.

But it might be unnecessarily complicated. As you are working with client-side JavaScript, you could include the URLs in a JavaScript array or object, instead of putting them anywhere in HTML markup. For example, you could use an object with thumbnail image URLs as property names and full image URLs as corresponding values, like

```
var fullImage = { 'thumb.png': 'actualImageUrl.png', ... }
```

And you would then use this object to pick up the full image URL when a thumbnail is clicked on.

For a more robust solution, which would work even when JavaScript is disabled, you would need to generate the code server-side, generating `a` elements around `img` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the URL of the `src` attribute is perfectly valid - But you could use the `data-` attribute - new with HTML5 (although that doctype is not a requirement to use them) and its purpose is exactly this, from the specs :

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.

[w3 specs for custom attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

**Note** - you can [test validation here](http://validator.w3.org/)